# React router not working root params

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, jsx

my react router work properly but when i add params router then display some error like Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';

import App from './containers/App';
import Greetings from './containers/Greetings';
import SignupPage from './containers/signup/SignupPage';
import Screen from './containers/signup/Screen1';
import LoginPage from './containers/login/LoginPage';

export default (
    <Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
         <IndexRoute component = {SignupPage} />
         <Route path = "signup" component = {SignupPage} />
         <Route path = "login" component = {LoginPage} />
         <Route path = "/screen/:id" component = {Screen} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "when i add params router then display some error like..."?

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of your router is possibly off - Adding spaces between props can cause syntax errors. Note I've also exported to a variable called router as this is a better practice to explicitly export. Try rewriting the router like this:

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';

import App from './containers/App';
import Greetings from './containers/Greetings';
import SignupPage from './containers/signup/SignupPage';
import Screen from './containers/signup/Screen1';
import LoginPage from './containers/login/LoginPage';



export default router = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <IndexRoute component = {SignupPage} />
         <Route path="signup" component={SignupPage} />
         <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
         <Route path="/screen/:id" component={Screen} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
)
```